# PreferenceActivity Colors/Theme Different in Emulator than on Device?

Tags: android, android-layout, preferenceactivity

I have created a PreferenceActivity and set up a style for it in style.xml, both the regular and the v21 version of the file. The color scheme is default but in the style I changed the accent color to orange...this works great on the AndroidStudio emulator.

However, when I install the apk on my phone (Galaxy s6) the orange color is not used and in general the whole layout looks different than the default layout on the emulator before I changed the accent color to orange.

Why is this? Is there something I need to change so that the style/theme I customized on Android Studio applies to devices as well?

My style:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/laborswipe_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/laborswipe_orange</item>
    </style>
```

My PreferenceActivity in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme"></activity>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceTheme has no parent. Also check if you override colors as expected inside this tag. Try this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/laborswipe_orange</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/laborswipe_orange</item>
</style>
```

Also check if ide is connected to emulator on Run and doesn't hang on "Waiting for device to come online". In that case - check if Android versions match in Grandle Script build.gradle for `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` and for emulator device. Check if theme is supported by these versions.